# show notify message after submitting popup form

Tags: angular

I'm showing a popup on button click, which has a form on it. I would like to have a notify message in the parent component, when the form is submitted. For this, I registered an output event and set a variable to true in this. Then I check this variable in te `ngOnInit` event and if it is true, then show the notify. But the notify doesnt't show. I think, due to the fact, that the `ngOnInit` event fires first and at this moment the boolean isn't true. So, the question is: how to get this work properly?

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxpopup-rux5wz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you send the events, we are sure the submit button is pressed when the `formSubmitted()` function is called in the parent component. So you could immediately trigger the notification within this function.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  formSubmitted() {
    this.submitted = true;
    notify({ message: "form submitted" }, "success", 2000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

But the page is reloaded every time the submit button is pressed. Not sure if this is the intended behavior.

Comment: At the end, I don't need a real submit and a page reload, because we are in Angular. And my problem was practically caused by the page reload. This gave me a hint to revise the inserting function. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

In `child.component.ts`, you will have to emit `true` or `false` on formSubmit.

```js
formSubmit() {
  this.submitButtonClicked.emit(true);
}
```

In the `app.component.ts`, remove the code from `ngOnInit()` and change like this.

```js
formSubmitted() {
  this.submitted = true;
  this.notifyMessage();
}

ngOnInit() { }

notifyMessage() {
  if (this.submitted) {
    notify({ message: "form submitted" }, "success", 2000);
  }
}
```

When you click on submit, you can see the green notification below.